# What's the easiest 100% for steel soul mode?

Tags: achievements, hollow-knight

I'm not the best at memorizing 20+ different boss patterns but I would really like to try out a Steel Soul 100% run in Hollow Knight.  With the 4 DLC additions (Hidden Dreams, Grimm Troupe, Lifeblood, and Godmaster), [the total percentage you can achieve is 112%](https://hollowknight.wiki/w/Completion), but you only need 100% to get the completion achievement.  That means there are ~12 of the harder pieces of the game that can be skipped and still get the achievement.

I can wait to do a lot of the bosses until I have a bunch of health and nail upgrades, but which things should I specifically avoid because they are too dangerous?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Funny enough, I just completed this achievement recently.  I can tell you what I avoided that made it easier for me.  You may choose to do some of these and trade them out if that is easier for you.

So I skipped the following:

- I did not fight Grimm, nor Nightmare King Grimm (2%)
- I did not get the last mask fragment for light from carrying that white flower to that
  grave (1%)
- I did not hear the Seer's final words by getting 2400 Essence (1%)
- I did not fight the warrior Markoth (1%)
- I did not complete the trial of the fools (1%)
- I did not get the King Soul/Void heart charm because I didn't
  trust my platforming skills in the White Palace (1%)
- I did not get the Godtuner and therefore did not do any of the pantheons (5%)

I believe that is how I did it. Also, a pro tip if you don't mind cheesing it a bit:  **Don't be afraid to pause and quit to menu when you get to low health.  You'll restart at your nearest bench with full health.**

Comment: Since there are 4 pieces of a mask, 3 others can be skipped as well such as saving Bretta and the one in Deepnest via the Fungal Core.  The Godtuner itself is easy to acquire (only requires a key), so a Warrior Dream or Traitor Lord might be a better choice.  Other than that, this is a great list!

Comment: @ChaseSandmann Great points!!  Honestly, I had forgotten where the key was for the Godtuner and was too lazy to look it back up when I did the run.  I was already at 100% by the time I would have gotten around to it.  Good luck!!

Comment: White Palace can be cheesed to an extent using the Hiveblood charm.

Comment: @Powerlord White Palace can be cheesed to an extreme using Deep Focus, Grubsong, and either Grubberfly's Elegy or Hiveblood. Deep Focus heals two health for 33 soul, and Grubsong provides 30 soul per two health lost, which is just shy of a net zero. Elegy increases Grubsong's contribution to 50 soul per two health lost, which is a net gain, or Hiveblood can be used to save an extra mask here and there for the same effect. With this combo, White Palace is completely safe, as long as you take it easy and remember to heal.

Comment: I would argue that hearing the Seer's final words by getting 2400 essence is a pretty safe 1% for Steel Soul mode, and the same is true for the pantheons if you're good enough to actually beat any of them. Because the pantheons and the boss dreams are technically dream fights, dying during those fights doesn't end your Steel Soul run, so there's nothing to worry about in that sense. Of course, skipping these might be easier and take less time, perhaps require less skill, but in terms of killing the run they're very safe options, if that's your main concern.